Sahih Muslim book of menstruation (310)
Anas b. Malik reported:
Umm Sulaim who was the grandmother of Ishaq came to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) in the presence of 'A'isha and said to him: Messenger of Allah, in case or woman sees what a man sees in dream and she experiences in dream what a man experiences (i. e. experiences orgasm)? Upon this 'A'isha remarked: O Umm Sulaim, you brought humiliation to women;may your right hand be covered with dust. He (the Holy Prophet) said to 'A'isha: Let your hand be covered with dust, and (addressing Umm Sulaim) said: Well, O Umm Sulaim, she should take a bath if she sees that (i. e. she experiences orgasm in dream).
My Question is what did the prophet Saw mean by saying ‘let your hand be covered with dust’ (he said this to Aisha RA)

As a Shia Muslim I have never heard of such a happening, but it if is correct then it might imply any Muslim who curses another Muslim with no right therein, the curse may return upto himself. Only a guess though.
